# Postfix Relay Forwarding

Tags: email, postfix

Необходимо завернуть всю почту от одного клиента (IP адреса с которого происходит отправка письма) или почтового ящика (поле "От"), в данном случае это единственные константы, на один определенный почтовый адрес, при этом полностью игнорирую поле "Кому".
Как это можно сделать штатными средствами?

P.S. Единственный способ, который я нашёл: включить локальную доставку писем на relay сервер для определенного клиента, а дальше при помощи procmail перенаправлять письма дальше.

Comment: для справки: помимо заголовка `to` есть ещё как минимум `cc` и `bcc`. см. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-4.5

Comment: В конкретно моём случае данные заголовке не испольщуются, так как осуществляется автоматическая персональная рассылка. Один адрес - одно письмо. Но действительно, как не подумал об этих заголовках. Спасибо!

Comment: на сайте программы есть обширная статья по этому поводу: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Comment: В документации описывается подмена отправителя, а мне же необходимо подменить получателя при совпадении адреса клиента (ip сервера, с которого инициировано пиьсмо).
Мне видится способ: фильтруем почтовую очередь на основании адреса клиента (ip адрес инициатора письма), далее мы должны затеперь отправителя и подставить своё значение, после только выплюнуть письмо в общую очередь и обрабатывать согласно стандартных правилам.
Загвоздка в том, что я не опнимаю, как подобную проверку инициировать и реализовать.

Comment: о, речь уже об ip-адресе. я думаю, в вопрос стоит внести уточнения.

Comment: У меня есть всего 2 неизменных значения: ip адрес с которого уходит письмо и значение поля "От". Остальные поля могут менять своё значение.

Answer (score 1):

предуведомление: не проверял работоспособность. ответ основан лишь на [этой информации](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/228099) и содержимом `man 5 access`.

---

согласно [`man 5 access`](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html), для решения можно воспользоваться файлом `/etc/postfix/access`.

для этого добавьте в этот файл строку:

```
sender@domain1 REDIRECT recipient@domain2
```

и выполните:

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/access
```

Comment: Данный способ я пробовал - не работает.